# margins of itemized list inside abstract

Tags: itemize

I am using the `Interact` latex style template from Taylor and Francis journals - [available here](http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/InteractAPALaTeX.zip). The journal I'm preparing a document for has a two-part abstract, in which the second section can be a bulleted list.

But when I try to use `\itemize` inside the `abstract` environment, the right margin of the list does not align with the rest of the abstract. How can I fix this?

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[british]{interact}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\articletype{RESEARCH ARTICLE}
\title{Article with bullet list inside abstract}
\author{\name{A.N. Other\textsuperscript{a}\thanks{Contact: A.N. Other. Email: someone@somewhere.edu}} 
\affil{\textsuperscript{a} Some University, Somewhere, XX 12345, USA}}
\maketitle 

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1].\\ 
\noindent\textbf{Policy Insights}
\begin{itemize}
   \item This line is way too long. It should align with the rest of the abstract. But it goes much too far too the right.
   \item It would be nice too if the bullets were left-aligned with the abstract. 
\end{itemize}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Keywords: Latex; Itemize; Lipsum
\end{keywords}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For standard classes this works as expected.  Where is `interact.cls` available from? Have you tried contacting the author of the class?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSwann - I included a link to the class in the 1st paragraph of the question.

Comment: If you're allowed to add other packages, I would use `enumitem` and the use `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=!,rightmargin=1in]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `enumitem`, setting `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` for the list to `1pc` and `5pc` respectively, as written l.36 of the code of the .cls file:

```
\documentclass[british]{interact}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\begin{document}
\articletype{RESEARCH ARTICLE}
\title{Article with bullet list inside abstract}
\author{\name{A.N. Other\textsuperscript{a}\thanks{Contact: A.N. Other. Email: someone@somewhere.edu}}
\affil{\textsuperscript{a} Some University, Somewhere, XX 12345, USA}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1].\\

\noindent\textbf{Policy Insights}
\begin{itemize}[wide, leftmargin = 1pc, rightmargin = 5pc]
  \item \lipsum[1].
  \item \lipsum[1].
\end{itemize}
 \lipsum[2-10]
\end{abstract}

\end {document}
```

[image]